# Basic - Understanding PHP object from Doctrine query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to work out how to handle the object this returns:

```
$data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:EntityName')->findAll();
```

I know I can pass it to Twig and use it that way, but I need to do further PHP code on it.

I suppose this is a general PHP question in dealing with objects.

Using serialise($data) returns so much info I don't know what to do with it.

I suppose I need to know something like this:

```
//to get record 1 / field 1
$data[1]['field1']
```

...but of course that doesn't work.

Comment: uh, it is an array of your Entities?? Can you be more clear? it would be $data[1]->getName()

Comment: No need to be more clear, and no need for 'uh' - the question is very clear. Maybe it's a silly question, maybe it's an obvious answer, but it wasn't to me. Your answer did help me to solve this though, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to serialize it, I think that would make it harder to work with.  Since Doctrine knows the type/class of entity your retrieved, its returned them as instances and you can interact with them normally.

An example based on your question:

lets say you want the record 1 - field 1 value, and this entity you searched for was structured something like this making field 1 the id:

```
Class Person {
    private $id;
    private $someValue;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setSomething($value)
    {
        $this->someValue = $value;
    }
}
```

You could do as Kris stated and use $data[0]->getId()
You can access any field you had getters and setters for (or was public)

If as you said you needed to perform some modifications to these retrieved objects, remember that $data is just an array objects/entities. You could do something like this:

```
foreach($data as $object)
{
    $object->setSomething($something);
}
```

I thinks it's definitely better to use them as objects